# SQL, return select results with different where clauses

Tags: sql

I have table whose column is just the length of a session and I would like to return the number of session that have zero length and the number of sessions that have length greater than zero.

I can do that with two separate commands

```
select count(session_length) from my_table where session_length=0

select count(session_length) from my_table where session_length>0
```

But I would like to see the results combined in one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one query using conditional aggregation.

```
select 
count(case when session_length = 0 then 1 end),
count(case when session_length > 0 then 1 end) 
from my_table
```

Comment: you have to change `count` to `sum`

Comment: i guess `count` would get you the same result.

Comment: you're right! `case` returns `null` which will not be counted.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 1 as QryNo, count(session_length) as SessLen
from my_table 
where session_length=0

union 

select 2 as QryNo, count(session_length) as SessLen
from my_table
where session_length>0
```

or

```
select 
    case
      when session_length = 0 then 1
      else 2
    end  as QryNo, 
    count(session_length) as SessLen
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be too simple so apologies if I have misread your query but Can you use

```
select count(session_length) from my_table where session_length >= 0
```

Again, Apologies if this is not what you're looking for.